# Синонимизировать [валидации]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

У нас идентичные метки — [валидация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f) (88 вопроса) и [validation](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/validation) (184 вопросов).

Предлагаю сделать основной русскую метку, так как у неё есть описание (хотя и меньше вопросов) и у нас принято русские метки делать основными.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Давайте сделаем основной меткой [валидация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f), так как там уже есть описание и слово уже успело стать привычным для русскоязычного обывателя.

Я вижу смысл делать англоязычними метки в случае, если мы в обычных предложениях и употребляем их на английском. К примеру, мы говорим (без коверканий): "Сделать сайт на PHP", а не "Сделать сайт на ПХП". А вот про валидацию мы будем писать "Проблемы с валидацией данных", а не "Проблемы с validation данных".

Answer (score 0):

Лучше описание перенести в [validation](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/validation) и основной сделать ее. Все таки более привычно, как на мой взгляд, и используется чаще.

Кроме того, сюда же красиво ляжет и под-метка [html-validation](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-validation)

Comment: Я на самом деле совершенно не против (лучше так, чем никак), но всё-таки слово "валидация" уже перекочевало в русский язык, и, как мне кажется, уже довольно привычно. Наверное, лучше запилить голосовалку по другому основному слову и пусть на основании её и выбирают.

Comment: Пилите, Шура :)

Comment: где-то была тема на мете, что основной нужно делать русскоязычную метку.

Comment: html-validation тоже можно переименовать в html-валидацию

Answer (score -9):

Validation (от лат. validus – здоровый, крепкий, сильный) – изначально латинское слово, которое попало в английский язык.

Я не вижу в нём ни капли русского! **Русскими буквами не значит по-русски!**

И как мы видим – большинство участников выбирают именно английское написание – именно поэтому и была создана, как я думаю, эта тождественная метка (<s>синоним</s>).

Можно было бы переименовать метку [валидация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f) в [проверка-входных-данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85), а метку [validation](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/validation) оставить как тождественную метку, но как говорит мой опыт – большинство русскоязычных разработчиков предпочитают английские понятия.

Поэтому было бы на мой взгляд правильно при наборе в метках [валидация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f) заменять её на [проверка-входных-данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85), а метку [validation](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/validation) оставлять как есть.

Иностранными словами в своём словарном обиходе мы убиваем то, что осталось от великого русского наследия, признаём чужое превосходство и теряем свою самобытность.

Давайте искоренять глупые и **без**смысленные новые заимствованные слова и гордиться великим и могучим русским языком. Это ведь так просто – и так правильно!

[image: русский язык, иностранные слова]

[image: русский язык, иностранные слова]

[image: русский язык, иностранные слова]

Comment: Почему валидация должна быть "проверка-входных-данных"? Чтобы сказать нескольки словами вместо одного, зато исконно русскими? Вас не смущает вообще наличие заимствованных слов в русском языке? К примеру, "компьютер" можно заменить на "электронно-вычислительную машину", хорошая же идея, правда?

Comment: @Vadim Ovchinnikov, Потому что [tag:validation] означает именно "проверку входных данных". Вы просто не задумывались об этом. Меня очень смущает наличие заимствованных слов в русском языке и поэтому я в своём окружении стараюсь быть последовательным моим взглядам и по возможности не употребляю иностранных слов. Многие думают, как и вы, что английское слово "computer" (от лат. computare - считать, вычислять) якобы незаменимо... Ещё и как заменимо – "вычислительное устройство"! ;-)

Comment: Хорошо, а программистов (тоже заимствованное слово) можно же называть "инженеры электронно-вычислительных машин", или как это будет на исконно русском?

Comment: @Vadim Ovchinnikov, "разработчики вычислительных устройств", "создатели вычислительных устройств".

Comment: Создатели вычислительных устройств — это те, кто в 60х первые компьютеры создали. А разработчики вычистильных устройств — это кто компьютеры создаёт, но не пишет для них программы.

Comment: Кстати, слова Паустовского, как и Тургенева — чистая ложь. Многие слова не имеют никакого аналога в русском языке и для того, чтобы их выразить приходиться употреблять кучу других слов, а в некоторых случаях даже осиливать статьи чтобы осилить понятия других культур. К примеру, как вы будете говорить про "дежавю", "испанский стыд"? Есть такая вещь, как ["непереводимость"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) и вряд ли есть смысл с ней бороться. Лучше — заимоствовать, расширяя наш язык.

Comment: @Vadim Ovchinnikov, я могу перевести на русский язык не только те слова, что вы написали выше, но и многие другие, но я считаю беЗполезной тратой времени пытаться доказывать это, т.к. вы со мной общаетесь не по существу и не хотите понять то, что я пишу. На этом я прекращаю спорить с вами.

Comment: Бесполезной пишется через "с".

Comment: На всякий случай напоминаю, что иногда валидируют не только входные данные, но и хранимые, а также выходные...

Comment: Если уж искать русский аналог, то это должна быть не многозначная "проверка данных", а ФЛК (формато-логический контроль). Но я за валидацию.

Comment: Давайте гордится великим и могучим 1C