# Почему все так стесняются русской культуры?

Tags: обсуждение

Почитал я   [это голосование](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2147/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-2015-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0#2152)  и очень поразился ответам на вопрос,

> Достаточно многие русскоязычные специалисты принципиально пользуются StackOverflow на английском (en.SO). Среди них есть как просто ищущие ответы, так и активные участники. Свое предпочтение они аргументируют примерно так (все примеры из личного опыта):
>
> На en.SO больше ответов и отвечающих, а на ru.SO мало участников, долго дают ответ
>   На ru.SO мало интересных вопросов, не на что отвечать
>   Английский — язык профессионального общения, поэтому нужно спрашивать на нем
>   SO на русском не нужен
>   Я не знаю, что есть SO на русском
>   Что бы вы на это возразили? Как можно привлечь русскоязычных программистов и системных администраторов к участию именно в StackOverflow на русском?

Меня поразили ответы, они были популистичные и несли едиство единство позиций.
Ситуация мне напомнила 89 год.

Из за такой позиции на [выборах 2017](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6051/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-2017-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0?rq=1) такой вопрос даже не прозвучал.

Почему так сложно людям которые находятся на этом сайте сказать :

я использую stackoverflow на русском из за того что я **человек русской культуры** или **я считаю свою культуру более лучшей и удобной для использования в своих целях**.

Или все администраторы этого сайта стыдятся свой культуры и происхождения?

Comment: Обычно под популизмом понимается несколько иное (Попули́зм (от лат. populus — народ) — Политика, апеллирующая к широким массам и обещающая им скорое и лёгкое решение острых социальных проблем.)

Comment: Мне кажется вы сами выдумали некое мнение "участники стесняются русского SO", ничем кроме личной "передернутой" инетрпретации его не подкрепили и просите вам опровергнуть еще более радикальное передергивание "все стыдятся"?

Comment: Внес изменения в ваш вопрос, чтобы он соответствовал [правилам сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). Поправьте, пожалуйста, если вы считаете их неверными.

Comment: А зачем мне драться с тем, чего по сути нет? Повторюсь - пока что есть только некая выдуманная установка. Аргументируйте, докажите то что есть по факту, тогда и поговорим со словами.

Comment: А что именно вы понимаете под русской культурой? Особенно в свете того, что это сайт для программистов и системных администраторов, то есть людей в первую очередь инженерного склада ума.

Comment: Так многие участники здесь не имеют с Россией ничего общего, кроме языка. Может "сложно сказать" лишь потому, что это не так?

Comment: А почему вы пишете неграмотно? Русский язык для вас не родной?

Comment: К сожалению, судя по отзывам и оценкам по следующей ссылке у меня сложилось впечатление, что **[русский язык здесь не только не любят, но ещё стараются им не пользоваться и заменять русские слова иностранщиной, а также не желают его изучать](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7463)** (<― ссылка). Это большое неуважение ко всем предкам!

Comment: @Bharata Это впечатление ложное. Здесь как раз сторонников чистоты языка полно. Ваш ответ заминусовали по простой причине - использование [проверка-входных-данных] в качестве метки неудобно и бессмыленно, как бы мы не любили русский язык, Паустовского и т.п.

Comment: @Arhad  инженерный склад ума не мешает вырождению и деградации.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Эм.. Я сейчас не вчитывался в детали (несколько не до этого), но, насколько я помню, вопрос был построен в форме "многие говорят вот такое и не хотят идти на SO - как бы вы их заманили?"

В этом контексте абсолютно неважно, к какой культуре и стране я отношусь (да, я тут, в том числе, из-за того, что русский), критерий переносится на заманиваемого. В принципе, если мы знакомы, то, скорее всего где-то рядом и он тоже русский (хотя бы в одном из смыслов).

Но вот сказать человеку: "Эй, а ведь русский язык - твой родной, бросай писать на английском и иди сюда" - на мой взгляд, является каким-то бредом. Никто никому ничего подобного не должен. Это как сказать: "Ты же русский - приведи мне медведя". Кстати, некоторая аналогия с [тыжпрограммистом](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6zl6VdvU8A) напрашивается.

В общем, культура и язык могут быть (и являются) причинами, по которыми человек находится здесь, но не могут быть способами приглашения. Для этого нужны какие-то более существенные факты. К тому же в рунете множество всяких сайтов с подходящей культурой, но зовём-то мы сюда, а не в рунет.

PS: Что касается культуры, кстати, у меня тут очень чётко складывается ощущение, что она подгоняется под бинайсность, хотя многие этого не хотят.

Answer (score 18):

Очень странная постановка вопроса.

Почему так сложно сказать именно эту фразу?

> Я использую stackoverflow на русском из за того что я человек русской культуры или я считаю свою культуру более лучшей и удобной для использования в своих целях

Потому что лично я не считаю эту фразу применимой лично ко мне, ни в части "я являюсь человеком русской (российской?) культуры", ни в части "русская культура применима к использованию в каких-то целях", особенно в целях разработки.

Я (как и многие другие посетители ruSO) - не русский. Ни по происхождению, ни по гражданству, ни по месту проживания. Да, для меня русский - это основной язык общения. Но это просто язык. Это не означает, что я чувствую себя частью "уникального духовного наследия русского народа с его традициями и обычаями", или вообще чего угодно, что вы вкладываете в слово "культура".

Если мне удобнее читать документацию по какой-то утилите на английском - я буду читать ее на английском. Не потому, что мне *стыдно* читать ее на русском, и не потому, что я *стыжусь* своего происхождения. Просто лично мне так удобнее. Если для другой утилиты удобнее читать инструкцию на русском - буду читать на русском.

Стыд и стеснение - это то, как лично вы воспринимаете ситуацию. Не стоит проецировать это ощущение на всех :)

Answer (score 7):

> не используют ruSO

&

> все администраторы этого сайта стыдятся свой культуры и происхождения?

<sub><sub><sub>*Почему у Стаса Михайлова нет песни про то, как он уважает ветеранов? Он что, не уважает ветеранов?*</sub></sub></sub>

---

Постановка вопроса не совсем корректна. Выводы сделаны поспешно, можно даже как оскорбление принять при желании.

В качестве своих пяти копеек добавлю, что (внезапно) далеко не все отвечающие на SO сидят здесь по причине своих альтруистических взглядов, желания помочь людям и так далее.

Как минимум два пункта можно выделить, почему enSO может быть более интересен (но это не значит, что эти пункты решающие/вынуждающие и т.д. и т.п.):

- Как бы ни было грустно это признавать, *качество вопросов на ruSO хромает*. 
  Не то, чтобы на enSO ситуация была сильно лучше, но разнообразия там больше, да и по причине большей активности и вероятность наткнуться на интересный вопрос тоже выше. А значит выше шансы что-то для себя почерпнуть, ведь далеко не всегда при ответе ты по теме вопроса уже собаку съел; тебе и самому интересно разобраться в проблеме.
- Корыстные помыслы: *10 тыщ репутации на ruSO это не 10 тыщ репутации на enSO*. Если рассматривать в качестве бонуса при устройстве на работу (тем более, вне русскоговорящего сегмента) количество репутации — у enSO явно преимущество выше. Да и репутация на ruSO может сказать в основном о технических навыках, а на enSO ещё и о знании языка минимум на базово-техническом уровне.

Всё это не означает, что кто-то ***стыдится*** русского сообщества. Встречал немало пользователей, у которых репутация даже в десятки раз выше на enSO, но они всё равно отвечают на ruSO. Да и я сам здесь чаще сижу, потому что коммьюнити (хотя я с ним не то чтобы контактирую) приятнее (если забыть конфликты с администрацией и уход хороших участников).

Answer (score 6):

На мой взгляд, на самом деле, ситуация обратная. Мы верим в людей, верим в русскоязычных разработчиков! [Мы уверены](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45468873#45468873), что в будущем главным источником знаний русскоязычного сообщества будет Stack Overflow на русском, а не какой–либо другой сайт, в том числе Stack Overflow на английском.

Уверен, что «мы» в, контексте абзаца выше — это и компания, и участники Stack Overflow на русском.

Пожалуйста, обратите также ваше внимание на:

- [Зачем нужен Stack Overflow на русском?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/173/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-stack-overflow-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC)
- [Зачем вы здесь?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C)
- [Can’t We All be Reasonable and Speak English?](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/02/13/cant-we-all-be-reasonable-and-speak-english/)